# how to handle textfield changes in MVI faster

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

let us say I have these functions in a ViewModel

```
    private val _event: MutableSharedFlow<Event> =
        MutableSharedFlow(extraBufferCapacity = 50)
    private val event = _event.asSharedFlow()
```

```
        viewModelScope.launch {
            event.collect {
                     is YachtsCheckoutViewModelContract.Event.EnterEmail -> onEmailEntered(event.text)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    private fun onEmailEntered(text: String) {
        setState {
            currentState.copy(
                email = text
            )
        }
    }
```

here is my view

```
 CheckoutTextField(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(top = 10.dp),
                        text = state.value.fullName,
                        onChange = viewModel::onFullNameEntered,
                        placeholder = "Full name",
                        fontSize = 13.sp,
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
                        //   isEnable = isEmailEnable,
                        errorText = "full name is not valid",
                        onValidation = { },
                        validator = String::isNotBlank
                    )
```

this is my mvi code, it is working however, the text typing is slow and the cursor sometimes goes between the characters, I do want to have single handle event function but this is not working very well , any ideas on how making this super fast